# differentiate scroll down and scroll up

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing an infinite scroll functionality. It works fine, the only issue is the ajax loading is happening when scroll down as well as scroll up. How to check the event is scroll down in jquery or javascript. How to get the current scroll position. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scrollTop` property for that. It gives you information about vertical scroll position. Remember old value in variable and then compare it with new one to determine scroll direction.

I believe you could find this property in the object passed to event handler. 
More info here http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php